# Adding resource files to an Azure App Service via a build or release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Assuming I have the following repo structure

```
common-images
src/webapi
src/webapi/images
```

What I would like to do is to copy files from `common-images` to a folder in the resulting webapi folder, so that I can reference them when running the API.

How can I do that using the Azure DevOps pipelines?

My guess would be that I could do this using a combination of "Copy Files" in the build pipeline, and then somehow using a "post script" in the App Service deployment, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding resource files to an Azure App Service via a build or release pipeline

You could add a MSBuild target to add those extra files to the package, so add following scripts to your project file `.csproj`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="PathToTheFiles\common-images\*.ts" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\*.ts</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Check [the ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293668/how-to-add-extra-files-to-the-package-that-is-generated-by-msbuild-called-by-an) for some more details.

Then, we could use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip) or [Azure App Service deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to  Azure App Service.

Hope this helps.